# Can't I use Vue2.7 with Webpack5?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, webpack-5

I've searched hours and red thousands posts, but I didn't found appropriate solution.

I want to use Webpack5 with Vue2.
Therefore I upgrade vue to ^2.7.14 and vue/cli and it's pulgins to ^5.0.6.
because when I saw the Official Doc of Vue and Vue CLI, it seems they support Webpack 5 if vue and vue/cli version like above.
(I refer to this page.)

[image]

[image]

But when I write `npm run serve` at terminal it still has error.

```
 ERROR  ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

        options should NOT have additional properties
        options should NOT have additional properties
        options should NOT have additional properties
        options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
        options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

    at validateOptions (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\schema-utils\src\validateOptions.js:32:11)
    at new ProgressPlugin (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:62:3)
    at new Progress (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\progress-webpack-plugin\index.js:25:21)
    at new progressPlugin (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\progress-webpack-plugin\index.js:127:10)
    at C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Plugin.js:14:18
    at Object.toConfig (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Plugin.js:78:22)
    at C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Config.js:129:63
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.toConfig (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Config.js:129:40)
    at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:277:34)
    at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\PluginAPI.js:132:25)
    at serve (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:75:31)
    at Service.run (C:\Project\workmanager-frontend\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:262:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I tried to delete node-modules and npm i
and package-lock.json and npm i
comment out /node=modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js

```
if (!process.env.VUE_CLI_TEST && options.devServer.progress !== false) {
        //   // the default progress plugin won't show progress due to infrastructreLogging.level
        //   webpackConfig
        //     .plugin('progress')
        //     .use(require('progress-webpack-plugin'))
        // }
```

but nothing works.

I could downgrade vue/cli, but before that I want to know that whether it's possible to use Webpack5 with vue 2.7, vue/cli5.

below is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.9",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.4",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/vue": "^5.11.4",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.3.0",
    "ag-grid-vue": "^25.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "billboard.js": "^2.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "chartkick": "^3.2.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "es-abstract": "^1.19.1",
    "floating-vue": "^1.0.0-beta.19",
    "hchs-vue-charts": "^1.2.8",
    "hooper": "^0.3.4",
    "i18next-scanner": "^4.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.10.377",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "prismjs": "^1.27.0",
    "quasar": "^2.2.1",
    "tippy.js": "^6.3.7",
    "translate-google": "^1.5.0",
    "v-calendar": "^2.4.1",
    "v-jsoneditor": "^1.4.5",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.15",
    "vue": "^2.7.14",
    "vue-advanced-cropper": "^1.8.2",
    "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-chartkick": "^0.6.1",
    "vue-codemirror": "^4.0.6",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.26.3",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-json-viewer": "^2.2.22",
    "vue-loading-overlay": "^3.4.2",
    "vue-prism-editor": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.5.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.3",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
    "vue-slide-up-down": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-spinner": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^4.3.1",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.22.6",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.0",
    "@storybook/vue": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/vue-webpack5": "^7.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.6",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.6",
    "chromatic": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.13",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "storybook": "^7.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.10.2"
  },
```

Comment: just go for vue 2.7 and vite

Comment: If i can I do, but now I have to use vue2.7 and webpack